# Japanese text in Java .properties file

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, properties

I am trying to read Japanese string values from a .properties file with the code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
properties.load(in);
```

The problem is apparently with the above code not recognizing the encoding of the file. It reads only the English portions and replaces the Japanese characters with question marks. Incidentally, this is not a problem with *displaying* Japanese text in Swing or *reading/writing* a UTF-8 encoded .properties file in an editor. Both things work.

Is the `Properties` class encoding-unaware? Is there an encoding-aware alternative that does not violate the security manager settings normally found in applets?

Comment: Are you seeing this (_reads only the English portions and replaces the Japanese characters with question marks_) on console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` expects ISO 8859-1 encoding, as [noted in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

In general you'll want to use `native2ascii` to convert property files, load using a reader, or use XML where you can specify encoding.

Comment: +1. I think it's simplest to load using a reader: replace `properties.load(in)` with `properties.load(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"))` (or whatever encoding you're using).

Comment: Thanks Eli, adding an InputStreamReader is indeed the easiest solution, with the smallest changes to the original code.

Comment: Dave's solution with native2ascii.exe does work, but it adds one more operation whenever the .properties file is edited, and the necessity to keep an original file in addition to the .properties file. Using a reader is simpler, as suggested. I feel XML is not practical in this case because of the added chance to introduce errors while manually editing the .properties file, and probably the code itself would be more complex than the above alternative.

Comment: @esav1953 That's why I provided the three main options, and in many or most situations using a reader is good option although your reasoning is a bit off. The conversion process is part of the build process; the extra step disappears-the properties file is a build artifact. Using XML isn't significantly (or any) more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion you have to convert Japanese character to java Unicode escape string

For example, this is the way I did with Vietnamese

```
Currency_Converter = Chuyen doi tien te  

Enter_Amount = Nh\u1eadp v\u00e0o s\u1ed1 l\u01b0\u1ee3ng  

Source_Currency = \u0110\u01a1n v\u1ecb g\u1ed1c  

Target_Currency = \u0110\u01a1n v\u1ecb chuy\u1ec3n  

Converted_Amount = K\u1ebft qu\u1ea3  

Convert = Chuy\u1ec3n \u0111\u1ed5i  

Alert_Mess = Vui l\u00f2ng nh\u1eadp m\u1ed9t s\u1ed1 h\u1ee3p l\u1ec7  

Alert_Title = Thong bao
```

Comment: @butchi Hello, when I input in Messages_vi_VN.properties file, each key input to file : into like that Convert = Chuy\u1ec3n \u0111\u1ed5i. But I only want input and display in VietNamese.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to read any language from properties file, what you should do is just get value by key from Properties file and then create a new string `new String(keyValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")`, that is, it will create a UTF-8 string for you.

```
public static String getLocalizedPropertyValue(String fileName, String key, Locale locale) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Properties props = getPropertiesByLocale(fileName, locale);
    String keyValue = props.getProperty(key);
    return keyValue != null ? new String(keyValue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8") : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) ?